# Playwright nightly (firefox) headed mode, browser is not responding

Tags: javascript, playwright, firefox-nightly

I am using

- playwright version 1.41.2
- node v21.6.1
- win11 Pro build 22631 x64
- Lenovo PC
- JavaScript and TypeScript.

I have an issue when running a test in headed mode with the Firefox (nightly) browser (firefox-1438). Browsers were installed over npm install @playwright. Every browser works fine (chromium, webkit, edge) except nightly in headed mode. In headless mode nightly works fine. Well, I am not receiving any error and testing is executed without a defect.

I am running a simple test delivered by the Playwright team.
Script:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('has title', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/);
});
```

What I did: uninstall node, uninstall pw and reinstall. Manually deleted browsers from ms-playwright folder and reinstalled them. Delete browser over command: npx playwright uninstall –all and reinstall.

Any ideas?

Comment: For pasting in code, don't add backticks to each line and within lines. Just add three backticks on a line, paste in the code untouched, and add three backticks on a line afterwards to close off the code block. I've fixed your code formatting here, but I had to make internal line changes, so you might want to check it to make sure the code still matches your intent.